# Random sampling with bias

Tags: sampling

Random sampling from a discrete interval is relatively simple. Here my code is Python, but also straightforward in R and others.

```
position = random.randint(1, 100)
```

I would like to introduce a small bias in the sampling so that it's slightly more likely to draw from the range `[75, 100]`. My naive first attempt was as follows.

```
position = random.randint(1, 100 + 25)
if position > 100:
    position -= 25
```

However this results in very elevated sampling *at both ends of the interval*. How would I 1) restrict the bias toward only one end of the interval; and 2) control the intensity of the bias?

Answer (score 2):

As the question was asked in terms of Python, I will answer in the same way:

You can use [numpy.random.choice()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.3/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html), which allows you to specify arbitrary weighting, via the `p` parameter.

The only annoying thing is that it requires `p` to be a probability array with sum = 1, rather than allowing an arbitrary weight array with entries >= 0. (So I always end up making a `normalize_sum` command.)